# How to make my bash script push changes to the githhub?

Tags: git, bash, github

So , I am just beginner to git . So , I thought of making a bash script file that simply have all the commands that I need to push to git . I have to just execute that script that's it .

```
#!/bin/sh
###########################

# add all added/modified files
git add *
# commit changes
git commit -m "made changes"
# push to git remote repository
git push origin master
###########################
echo Press Enter...
read
```

I want to ask , can I add more to this script such that it also fills the username and password for me instead of doing it manually .

Comment: Sure. But it's probably easier and safer to set up an [ssh connection](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) if you want a password-free connection.

Comment: Instead, upload to github a ssh-key and skip the user password completely.

Comment: @Chris . My college blocks ssh connection . So if you can tell me the changes that I should make in the script file to achieve it . It will be very helpful

Comment: @DeveloperNodejs

Comment: @AtifImam Wow, that's obnoxious. You should be able to still connect to github through [ssh over the https port](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/), which is exceedingly unlikely to be blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

You will need to put in your username/password the first time you push after this; after that git will remember both indefinitely.